# linux user cant access file that he is a part of

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I have created a group called `mrp` and assigned the normal user and the `root` and then assigned it to the file:

```
chgrp mrp /usr/bin/mplayer

chown root:mrp /usr/bin/mplayer
```

But, once I login as normal user I cant seem to access `mplayer`, `which mplayer` says file not found.

What can be the issue?

Comment: Does the output of `echo $PATH` for that user contain `/usr/bin`?

Comment: you've changed the owner and group of the file. but how about the permissions of the file?

Comment: @nKn it doesnt contain that path, how do I add this path ?

Comment: Edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add this at the bottom: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`. Then logout and login and try to call `which` again. That if the shell for the user is `/bin/bash`, you can check in the `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: @nKn, I editied the bashrc file and yes the shell for the user is /bin/bash, im still unable to access the file though

Comment: @DavidDai , the permissions of the file are rwxrwxr--, so the group does have full permissions on the file